# How to change VNC Viewer resolution in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, resolution, arch-linux, vnc

The best resolution of my monitor is `2560*1440`, and the maximum resolution of my current VNC Viewer is just `1920*1200`:
[image]
I want to change the resolution, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
$ vncserver :6 -geometry 2560*1440
vncserver: geometry 2560*1440 is invalid
```

How can I change the resolution of VNC Viewer in Arch Linux?

Comment: You would have to follow what others have done in this page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816/changing-the-resolution-of-a-vnc-session-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find answer myself:
(1) Modify ~/.vnc/config file:

```
## Supported server options to pass to vncserver upon invocation can be listed
## in this file. See the following manpages for more: vncserver(1) Xvnc(1).
## Several common ones are shown below. Uncomment and modify to your liking.
##
# securitytypes=vncauth,tlsvnc
# desktop=sandbox
geometry=2560x1440
# localhost
# alwaysshared
```

(2) Restart the VNC server, then I can select `2560X1440` resolution:
[image]

BTW, I should use **x**, not ***** in `2560X1440`.